# Why does filepath.Walk() panic?

Tags: go

I am trying to code up the wiki for go programing language.
I have put the data in `/data` folder and `.html` files in the `/tmpl` folder.

I have coded up the `main` function as follows

```
func main() {
    walk := func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if err == nil && !info.IsDir() && filepath.Ext(path) == ".html" {
            http.HandleFunc("/view/", makeHandler(viewHandler))
            http.HandleFunc("/edit/", makeHandler(editHandler))
            http.HandleFunc("/save/", makeHandler(saveHandler))
        }
        return err
    }
    root := TEMPLATE_PATH + "edit.html"
    err := filepath.Walk(root, walk)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
}
```

I am getting `panic edit.html not found`. Could anyone please guide me?

Comment: What is your TEMPLATE_PATH, and does it relate to where you put edit.html? Are you following along from someone else's code?

Comment: var TEMPLATE_PATH := "tmpl/".

Comment: is there an edit.html in your tmpl folder?

Comment: yes there is edit.html in tmpl folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation of filepath.Walk](http://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Walk) you can read:

> func Walk(root string, walkFn WalkFunc) error
>
> Walk walks the file tree rooted at root, calling walkFn for each file or directory in the 
>   tree, including root. All errors that arise visiting files and directories are filtered by 
>   walkFn. The files are walked in lexical order, which makes the output deterministic but 
>   means that for very large directories Walk can be inefficient.

So `Walk` expects a directory as first parameter. You're putting a file in there, which
makes the whole thing throw a panic.

I'm not sure what you're attempting to do, but if you want to open that file, use [`os.Open`](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#Open) or `os.Stat` if you want to test for existance.

A general tip when coding in go: Use the `gofmt` command to format your code according to the [style guidelines](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#formatting).